# Getting views in Activity from fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

In my project i have a simple class to retrieve location..it has a static Fragment as innerclass.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    GPSTracker gps;
    double mylatitude, mylongitude;
    TextView txt_location;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txt_location = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.current_location);


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();

            }


            gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);


            if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

                mylatitude = gps.getLatitude();
                mylongitude = gps.getLongitude();

                String latis = Double.toString(mylatitude);
                String longis = Double.toString(mylongitude);
                Log.d("my",latis+ "location to string is done   " + longis);
                txt_location.setText(latis+longis);
            }

    }



       public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {


        public PlaceholderFragment() {

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);

        }
    }

}
```

The code is showing `NullPointerException` at    `txt_location.setText(latis+longis);`.

Logcat log is as follows:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1051)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I found That error is because it can not find `txt_places` from `(TextView) findViewById(R.id.current_location);`(There isn't any mistake in XML file), because it is the view in fragment's xml not in Activity's. How do I access it in Activity?

Comment: Just a sidenode: IMHO it is a bad design to change a `Fragment`'s `View` from the `Activity` it is attached to. A method should be called on the `Fragment` from the `Activity` so that the `Fragment` always handles its own UI, not its parent `Activity`.

Comment: can you explain in answer? I'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are having the `TextView` inside the fragment and the `Location` related methods in the activity is completely wrong. Move all of them to one place. Either move the `Location` related methods inside the fragment, or move the layout from the fragment to the activity.

something like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();

        }
 }

   public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

   GPSTracker gps;
   double mylatitude, mylongitude;
   TextView txt_location;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
         txt_location = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.current_location);


        gps = new GPSTracker(getActivity());


        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

            mylatitude = gps.getLatitude();
            mylongitude = gps.getLongitude();

            String latis = Double.toString(mylatitude);
            String longis = Double.toString(mylongitude);
            Log.d("my",latis+ "location to string is done   " + longis);
            txt_location.setText(latis+longis);
        }



        return view;

    }
}

}
```

Comment: Then how can we write     gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this); ...as expected it is showing error.

Comment: insetaed of `MainActivity.this` use `getActivity()`. Its just asking a context there..

Answer (score 1):

Modify onCreateView method like that:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
    txt_location = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.current_location);

    return view;

}
```

Comment: I have tried it...but since my fragment is static (because it is inner class fragment)...it can not access textview txt_places

Comment: Remove static modifier.

Comment: then it will show another error that inner class fragment must be static

Answer (score 1):

*My sidenote as an answer, as the OP requested.*

**IMHO it is a bad design to change a `Fragment`'s View from the `Activity` it is attached to.**

A method should be called on the `Fragment` from the `Activity` so that the `Fragment` always handles its own UI, not its parent `Activity`.
That would mean that your `Activity` (let's say `MainActivity`) keeps a variable to its `Fragment`s (lets say `MyFragmentA` and `MyFragmentB`).

To update the UI of any of `MainActivity`'s `Fragment`s you should call a method that will do the work: `myFragmentA.updateUI()`.
So that the `Fragment` will only be the one to truly touch its UI.
It's not MVC design pattern, but cleaner anyway.

In your case `TextView txt_location` seems to be a `View` inside a `Fragment`, so the variable `txt_location` itself should not be declared in the `Activity` but in the `Fragment` it is displayed in.

1. This makes the code a lot cleaner.
2. You can truly respect the lifecycle of your objects, being an `Activity` (`onCreate()`, `onResume()` etc) or a `Fragment` (`onCreate()`, `onCreateView()`, `onViewCreated()` etc) which differs.

**Answer**

Again, in your case `(TextView) findViewById(R.id.current_location)` makes no sense from the `Activity` point of view, since `current_location` is not in its view, but in one of its children: a `Fragment`.

Place `txt_location = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.current_location);` in `onCreateView()` of your `Fragment` and use `txt_location.setText()` in `onViewCreate()` or later (again in the `Fragment`).

Answer (score 0):

this is very easy . just add getActivity() before findviewbyid for example :

```
EditText et = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbarsrch);
```